Cohere method chat_stream does not accept 'messages' parameter
I am currently training myself in using the Cohere API. I am following the training course Building a chatbot. You can find my code below.
According to the API Refence, I should be able to pass the argument 'messages' to the method chat_stream
But it fails with the following error:
BaseCohere.chat_stream() got an unexpected keyword argument 'messages'

Could you please help me ? any idea about what I am doing wrong?
# Create a conversation ID
conversation_id = str(uuid.uuid4())

# system message
system_message = "you are a coach of tennis"

print('Starting the chat. Type "quit" to end.\n')

while True:

    # User message
    user_message = input("User: ")

    bot_messages=[
        {'role':'system', 'content': system_message},
        {'role':'user', 'content': user_message}
        ]

    # Typing "quit" ends the conversation
    if user_message.lower() == 'quit':
        print("Ending chat.")
        break

    # Chatbot response
    stream = co.chat_stream(
                            model="command-r-plus",
                            messages=bot_messages,
                            conversation_id=conversation_id
                            )

    print("Chatbot: ", end='')

    for event in stream:
        if event.event_type == "text-generation":
            print(event.text, end='')
        if event.event_type == "stream-end":
            chat_history = event.response.chat_history

    print(f"\n{'-'*100}\n")

